# Sylius installing dependences CmfCreateBundle

Tags: sylius

When i logged i get this error.

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@CmfCreateBundle/Resources/public/vendor/create/lib/jquery-htmlclean/jquery.htmlClean.js".") in "CmfCreateBundle::includejsfiles-hallo.html.twig".
```

What happend? I donsen't touch anything, just install Sylius following their documentation and trying to loggin as Admin.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it:

First, add "**Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CreateBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::downloadCreate**" to your root **composer.json** file like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreate"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreate"
    ]
},
```

Second, run command `composer run-script post-install-cmd`